# awk by multiple conditions in two files and change value in another column

Tags: awk, compare

I have two files like below

file 1

```
A G 1
T C 2
C G 3
G A 4
```

file2

```
G A 1
T C 2
C G 3
A G 4
```

I would like to compare if value in column 1 in file1 is same as column 2 in file2, and value in column 2 in file1 is same as column 1 in file2. (in other words, the values in column 1 and 2 are reversed)

if the row satisfy the condition, then make the value in column 3 negative, which will get

outputfile

```
A G -1
T C 2
C G 3
G A -4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1,$2]; next} ($2,$1) in a{$3 = -$3} 1' file2 file1
A G -1
T C 2
C G 3
G A -4
```

- `NR==FNR{a[$1,$2]; next}` save first and second column of `file2` as key in `a` array
- `($2,$1) in a` if second and first column of `file1` matches as a key in `a` array

  - `$3 = -$3` multiply third column with `-1`. If you just want to add a `-` regardless of content in third column, use `$3 = "-"$3`
- `1` idiomatic way to print contents of `$0`

Comment: Hi Sundeep. Thanks for your answer. I tried your code but all the values in column 3 turn negative. I am not sure why this happen

Comment: @a.xue, did you try it on sample input files in question or actual input? and what is your awk version?

Comment: when using the sample input, the output is correct. But when I try acutal input, all the values turn negative. the version of my awk is 3.1.7

Comment: @a.xue can you paste few lines (modify sensitive info if any) from actual input to the question?